# EF4 one to one on code first and existing database and without foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I am trying to map an existing db to POCO classes using the fluent API. Everything works fine with one to many and many to many relationships but one to one fails with the gazillions of options I tried.

The sql tables are simple, `Agent` with `AgentID` as PK and `AdditionalAgentInfo` with `AdditionalAgentInfoID` as PK and a column `AgentID`. `Agent` does NOT have an `AdditionalAgentInfoID`, but I added this in my test db to see if this will solve it with no luck.

All the posts point out to do:

```
        pModelBuilder.Entity<Agent>()
              .HasOptional(u => u.AdditionalAgentInfo)
              .WithRequired(x => x.Agent);
        pModelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalAgentInfo>()
        .HasRequired(u => u.Agent)
        .WithOptional(x => x.AdditionalAgentInfo);
```

My context loads but `Agent.AdditionalAgentInfo` is always NULL. Looking into the profiler, the sql tries to join on the wrong column:

```
FROM [dbo].[AdditionalAgentInfo] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[AdditionalAgentInfoID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

it should be :

```
FROM [dbo].[AdditionalAgentInfo] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[AgentID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

So I tried to add `Map(x=>x.MapKey("AgentID")` but than I get duplicate columns error.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because EF supports only shared PK one-to-one mappings. The `AdditionalAgentInfo` PK should also be a FK to `Agent` table. Otherwise you have to map it as one-to-many relationship and ignore the `many` end property.